# HighCharts We are unable to add stacked bars on y axis as a time

Tags: highcharts

Adding code snippet which is using

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['M1']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    min: 1420063200000,
    max: 1420063920000,
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    reversed: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Idle',
    data: [1420063500000]
  }, {
    name: 'Idle1',
    data: [1420064200000]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
      type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
      text: 'Stacked bar chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
      categories: ['M1']
  },
  yAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
          min: 1420063200000,
          max: 1420063920000,
      title: {
          text: 'Total fruit consumption'
      }
  },
  legend: {
      reversed: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
      series: {
          stacking: 'normal'
      }
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'Idle',
      data: [1420063500000]
  },
  {
      name: 'Idle1',
      data: [1420064200000]
  }]
});

Comment: This is the sample code sample for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have added min and max limit because of which it's not showing you the other chart as that data is out of limit. Either change the min and max value or change the data.

I tried the same example without min and max limits its working fine.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['M1']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    reversed: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Idle',
    data: [1420063500000]
  }, {
    name: 'Idle1',
    data: [1420064200000]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is out of your `min` and `max` range. Values: `1420063500000` and `1420064200000` are stacked which creates `2840127700000` value. You problably want to use:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Idle',
    data: [700000]
}, {
    name: 'Idle1',
    data: [1420063500000]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ncvk7pwt/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.stacking